# Find the height of a map at the mouse in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project I have a top down view of a map, created with a heightmap and color coded. I want users to be able to place boats onto the map by clicking where they want them to go, but only if they click water. Any way to make this happen? Not sure if I did a very good job explaining myself, so ask and I'll try to clarify.

EDIT: Based off Soviut's response below it seems a better way of doing what I want to do is to cast a ray and check the distance, and compare that to find out if it hits water or land. So far I've done this based off an example I found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-distance.html):

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray downRay = new Ray(Vector3.down, Input.mousePosition);
Physics.Raycast(downRay, out hit);
Debug.Log(hit.distance);
```

This does return a distance, but the values do not seem to be correct. Is it something to do with the way I'm putting the numbers into new Ray(...)?

Comment: Please update your answer with your attempt. StackOverflow is not a code writing service, we need to see your code in order to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't supply any example of what you've tried, this answer is going to be general approach only.

You wouldn't be searching for the pixel colour at the mouse, you would be sampling either the height of the hightmap or the colour at the UV coordinate on the surface. You would get that coordinate by casting a ray in screen space, converting it to world space to detect the collision, converting the collision position to UV coordinates and then referencing the height map or colour map for the value at that UV coordinate. If the hight is low enough to be considered water, or the colour of water, place a boat.

Comment: I added some more detail on what I'm currently doing based on your suggestion